# cap:deploy not updating gems - need to run cap deploy:stop and cap deploy:start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, spree

I have a Spree application, and also maintaining a bunch of gems along with it.

Whenever I do a `cap deploy`, I find that I have to do `cap deploy:stop` and `cap deploy:start` in order for the changes made in the gems to be picked up.

Am I during this right, because this is obviously very disruptive to the users.

My setup follows mostly from the Railscasts episodes on Capistrano, Unicorn and Nginx.

**UPDATE:**

After a bit of research, I realized that I didn't include this in `unicorn.rb`.

```
before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{root}/Gemfile"
end
```

Could this be the cause?

Comment: You're committing your Gemfile, right? Bundler is on server? Do you get any bundler errors.

Comment: So its `git push` then `cap deploy`. No bundler errors. Just that I have to do `cap deploy:stop` and `cap deploy:start` for the changes to be picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have automatic bundle:

- You must `require 'bundler/capistrano'` in your capistrano config file
- You must not run your `cap deploy` with the option `no_release`

To troubleshoot, you need first to ensure that `deploy:finalize_update` is ran bu capistrano, you could create a scenario that run `before "deploy:finalize_update"` and just output som debug text to your console, you'll know the if the problem occurs before or after finalize_update

Comment: Yep. That's in the first line of my `config/deploy.rb`.

Comment: Edited my answer with more detail, please check and let me know the troubleshooting result so I can search further

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I'll update you tomorrow when I can test it out. :)

Comment: Hey. Any result so far?

Comment: In turns out there was a slight typo in my `unicorn_init.sh` file. There are still other slight issues ... but now the gems can be updated. :)